# WordPress Redirection Plugin Redirect

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, plugins

I'm trying to redirect a page and any subpages to the root but I can't find a way of doing it. I'm using the redirection plugin (https://redirection.me/). I would rather doing it via the plugin to keep all redirects in one place rather than .htaccess.

I would like to redirect `https://www.example.co.uk/developments/` and any subpages e.g. `https://www.example.co.uk/developments/test` or `https://www.example.co.uk/developments/another-test` etc. to the home page.

I tried just now it seemed to break the subpages so I had to revert the redirect.

This is what I was trying to use in the source URL:
`/developments/development-name/*`

And the target URL:
`/`

With `REGEX` and `Ignore Slashes` enabled.

Comment: You can do this easily with `htaccess`  instead of using the plugin

Comment: Yes, but Ideally I'd like my redirects in one place and all of them are in the plugin.

Comment: How many URLs are there to redirect ? You can use a cath-all pattern to redirect all of those URLs . `Not my DV`.

Comment: _"This is what I was trying to use in the source URL: `/developments/development-name/*`"_  - you said you wanted to redirect `/developments/` and everything below, so it should be just `/developments/*` then, no?

Comment: If you are using a regex (having selected "Regex" in options of the redirection.me plugin) then you need to use an appropriate regex. ie. `.*`, not simply `*`. `/developments/.*`. Or remove the `.*` altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/developments/development-name/*` is not what you want.  It looks like you are trying to do globbing with that `*`.  In regex, the equivalent of a glob `*` is `.*` where `.` means "any character" and `.*` means zero or more of any character.

The rule that would implement a redirect to the home page is:

- source: `/developments/.*`
- target: `/`

However, redirecting to the home page is not usually a good idea.  It is usually better to remove the content and show a custom `410 Gone` error saying why the content was removed.  When you redirect to the home page:

- Users don't get a meaningful error message and get frustrated with the bad user experience
- Search engines call it a "soft 404" error and treat it just like the content was removed, so you don't get any SEO benefit.

Comment: Thank you! Just to clarify this is what I used in the end for my source with regex:
^/developments/development-name/.*